# Value object as identity with Doctrine ORM and Symfony2 form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

So, I have this Doctrine entity mapped on MySQL:

```
Dende\Calendar\Domain\Calendar:
  type: entity
  table: calendars

  embedded:
    id:
      class: Dende\Calendar\Domain\Calendar\CalendarId
      columnPrefix: false

  fields:
    name:
      type: string
      nullable: false
      length: 255
```

mapping definition of embedded class looks like this:

```
Dende\Calendar\Domain\Calendar\CalendarId:
  type:   embeddable

  id:
    id:
      type: guid
      generator: { strategy: UUID }
```

everything works smoothly except one thing. I use "Calendar" entity in entity field type for symfony form. Field is added in form using form builder like this:

```
$builder
            ->add("calendar", "entity", [
                "class" => "Dende\Calendar\Domain\Calendar",
                "choice_label" => "name",
                "placeholder" => "Choose calendar",
            ])
```

It's displayed ok when filling the form, but after submitting it I receive en exception saying that:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 106: Error: Expected
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got '.'

As I found in stack trace, there's a query build with 'id.id' parameter (which makes sense because Calendar->id() returns CalendarId and it also has id() method) and that causes error (afterwards, when parsing):

```
 ORMQueryBuilderLoader ->getEntitiesByIds ('id.id', array('calendar_5629f2d738efc'))
```

Can anybody help me, what to do in this case? Is this some edge case of doctrine or error in my mapping? Everything beside of this works fine.

I use Symfony 2.7 and Doctrine2.6

Edit:

as far as I found, there could be a problem in generated query:

```
SELECT e FROM Dende\Calendar\Domain\Calendar e WHERE e.id.id IN(:ORMQueryBuilderLoader_getEntitiesByIds_id.id)
```

and probably it's a matter of last dot bettween id and id above. When I run this DQL query using app/console I get same error. After changing dot to underscore, there's only too few parameters exception.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you cannot use an embedded object as a primary key.  Which is a bit of a shame.  You should be able to create a custom type which can be a bit of a pain but should work pretty much the same way. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/doctrine-user/YSoEWzDvsFY.